# Is such a function possible

Tags: functions, continuity

Is it possible for a *non-piecewise*, *non-gif* function to have a value at a point but *not* be continuous at that point? (Eg. at x=2, f(2) exists, but the function is not continuous at x=2). Please provide a suitable example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nonpiecewise Function Defined at a Point but Not Continuous There](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651381/nonpiecewise-function-defined-at-a-point-but-not-continuous-there)

Comment: Yes, thank you!